# How to add more orderer nodes to a running hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have setup a hyperledger fabric network with 1 orderer node, but don't know how to add more orderer node to a running production hyperledger network.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firstly, your network ordering service has to be setup as a Kafka one, not solo. You can do this in your configtx.yaml file under OrdererType. You will then also have to create kafka brokers, zookeepers and configure all that. If you are not familiar with this, I found experimenting and studying this repo https://github.com/keenkit/fabric-sample-with-kafka very helpful.

Assuming you have a working network with a Kafka Ordering Service, adding an extra orderer is done via a channel update, which is very similar to adding a new org. There are quite a few steps involved but they are all listed and explained here http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html. I would recommend you understand how adding an org works first, but if you feel comfortable then the only differences for adding an orderer are:

- obviously there is no need to create new org crypto materials but you will need the crypto materials for another orderer
- instead of running the command `jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"Org3MSP":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ./channel-artifacts/org3.json > modified_config.json` which adds the new org crypto material to the network, open the json file and look for "OrdererAddresses". There should be an array of orderers there under another tag "addresses". Add your orderer here and just save the file as modified_config.json. You can then just run the same commands moving forward.
- when you sign the envelope using `peer channel signconfigtx -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb` bootstrap your CLI with an active orderer and use the OrdererMSP as otherwise the orderer will reject your transaction. Organisation MSP's, which are used for adding new orgs, will not work.

To help troubleshoot, I found it easier to initially spin up the 2 Orderer setup that the github repo above creates and then test removing 1 orderer, followed by adding it back in. After that experiment further with adding a 3rd.

Just as a side note you can find all the other things that can be changed with a channel update here: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/config_update.html. Click "Click here to see the config" to see an example of the json config (Note: the example is a solo not a Kafka).

Step by step (as requested):

1. In crypto-config under OrdererOrgs: Specs: create a new hostname for your orderer (using the same domain and name as your other).
2. Run the command `cryptogen extend --config=./crypto-config.yaml` NOTE: the 'extend' part so it generates what you need and not regenerate everything.
3. Spin up a new orderer container that is essentially identical to another orderer except the crypto volumes point to the new crypto generate in step 2, (and perhaps different port depending on your setup). You may notice at this point it is connected to the kafka brokers and has your channel and blocks because it is using the same genesis block. What needs to be done though is the network needs to be made aware of the address of this new orderer.
4. `docker exec -it cli bash` into your CLI container and bootstrap it with an active orderer information as you will need the OrdererMSP to sign off this change.

Bootstrap e.g. (yours might be different): `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp`

`CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=orderer0.example.com:7050`

`CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP`

`CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/tls/ca.crt`

`ORDERER_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem`

`CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel`

5. install jq in the CLI container to convert blocks to json and back `apt update && apt install -y jq`
6. fetch the latest config block `peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA`
7. convert to json and trim headers `configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config > config.json`
8. open the json file look for "OrdererAddresses" and under that heading there should be another tag "addresses". Add the new IP and PORT for the new orderer in that array. Save the change as modified_config.json
9. covert json form step 7 to block `configtxlator proto_encode --input config.json --type common.Config --output config.pb`
10. convert json from step 8 to block `configtxlator proto_encode --input modified_config.json --type common.Config --output modified_config.pb`
11. calculate the delta between block in step 9 and 10 `configtxlator compute_update --channel_id $CHANNEL_NAME --original config.pb --updated modified_config.pb --output org3_update.pb`
12. change the delta back to json `configtxlator proto_decode --input org3_update.pb --type common.ConfigUpdate | jq . > org3_update.json`
13. wrap the json in a header `echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"mychannel", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat org3_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > org3_update_in_envelope.json`
14. convert it back to block `configtxlator proto_encode --input org3_update_in_envelope.json --type common.Envelope --output org3_update_in_envelope.pb`
15. Since you are bootstrap as an active orderer you can just submit it, as the submitting party gives you a free signature and its the only one you need `peer channel update -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer0.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA`

Once your peers get this new block, they now know the address of the new orderer and can contact it.

Comment: it would be nice If you can provide a step by step process, would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: I have added that in. There are a lot of steps that's why I decided just to link http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html#prepare-the-cli-environment and point out the major differences because the process is very similar and understanding of one results in pretty much the understanding of the other.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, It worked and also is there a way to verify whether calls are going to second orderer?

Comment: `docker stop` and `docker start` helped me here. The leader peer of each org seems to "stick" to an orderer once it is elected for as long as it is alive. You should be able to see which orderer a peer is listening to from the peer logs. Since it is more than likely listening to your previous orderer, try running `docker stop <containerName>` on it to see if the leader peer swaps to your new orderer. If it is stuck polling for orderers and your other orderer is up, it means it still doesn't know its address or the address was wrong.

Comment: @AntonioGlavocevic if we are creating network with multiple orderer and multiple anchor peers then do the number of kafka and zookper will change? If yes then how to select the number of kakfa and zookeeper with respect to number of orderer or anchor peer?

Comment: @ShalabhNegi it is not a requirement to increase the number of kafka and zookeeper nodes but it will improve through put as the number of orders increase. Each orderer can talk to a different kafka node so it is up to you if you believe additional kafka nodes are required to handle the traffic. I don't think anchor peers have any affect on the kafka cluster, they are there just to announce themselves globally to the network. As for zookeeper, I have heard 3 is a good number to stop split brain and you should realistically never need more than 5.

Comment: @AntonioGlavocevic I was trying to create a network in which i have 5 organization having 2 peer each but amongst them only organization have 3 peers out of which it have 2 anchor peer. I have added in the profile of that organization in configtx.yaml file and have done onfigtxgen -profile GlobalOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate \
    ./channel-artifacts/GlobalMSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg GlobalMSP
  configtxgen -profile GlobalOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate \
   ./channel-artifacts/GlobalMSPanchors2.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg GlobalMSP

Comment: but it is throwing error Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application/GlobalMSP at version 0, but got version 1   I have just changed the values in the first-network file according to my need.    in script.sh i have updated it echo "Updating anchor peers for global..."
updateAnchorPeers 0 3
echo "Updating anchor peers for global..."
updateAnchorPeers 1 3    in utils.sh

Comment: eer channel update -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}anchors2.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA >&log.txt                                    eer channel update -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}anchors.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA >&log.txt

Comment: @AntonioGlavocevic thanks for the amazing and cleanest answer, i was stuck on this for quite long. Though i'm using raft but steps were similar and had to make few changes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Antonio's answer, you will then need to volume the genesis block of the system channel into your new orderer.

you can obtain it by fetching it from the existing orderer and selecting the channel name to be testchainid(default name)